# Can't see any shared links in Facebook when I filter my news feed by a friend list

Tags: facebook, links, feeds

I have 1000+ friends on Facebook who make 10K posts each day. I have a friend list with about 100 people and when I select this list on the news feed, I can't see the links they shared.

I can see the shared links both on the unfiltered news feed and on profile pages, but links disappear on friend list feed.